# UIButton created inside UIView which is child of scrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

I am creating `UIScrollView` on main view, then I am creating `UIView` which is child of `UIScrollView` and creating `UIButton` which is child of `UIView`.

When I am calling next `ViewController` on touch up inside event occur,first time it is taking time to load next view controller and second time not.

Flow:-

> Main View -> scroll View -> uiview -> uibutton

Comment: Show some code. How are you presenting the view?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution

in viewDidLoad method of FirstViewController

```
[subView addSubview:btn];
[scrollView addSubview:subView];
[self.view addSubView:scrollView];
```

Then Button Action Method

```
-(IBAction)actionGo:(id)sender
{
  NextViewController *nextVC = [NextViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"NextViewController" bundle:nil];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextVC animated:YES];    
}
```

in NextViewController.m

```
-(IBAction)actionBack:(id)sender
{
  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I am using storyboard,not adding control dynamically.

Comment: For this did you give segue directly? I mean did you do directly push the view from button without using coding?

Answer (score 0):

In first time when you run ViewController it unpacked data from XIB/Storyboard. This operation is taking some time. All other times when you call methods on you controller it will be cached and call immediately.